# Retrofit adding extra slash to the serialized JSON multipart string

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I believe it's Retrofit that's adding the extra slash to the key value pairs when calling the service with serialized JSON data.
I have a hash map object to be passed as a multipart string, and I'm converting it to JSON string using Gson.

```
public static String getJsonString(Object object) {
    gson = new Gson();
    jsonString = gson.toJson(object);
    return jsonString;
}
```

I have the retrofit builder like

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(path)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(trustCert(context))
            .build();
```

Passing the JSON data as

```
Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = ApiClient.getInstance(context).getApiService().uploadData(getJsonString(params));
```

Api interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadData(@Part("data") String data);
```

When we debugged on the server side, the received json data has extra slashes in it. For example, it's supposed to be like \"{\"key1\", \"value\"}\" but it is being serialized as \\"{\\"key1\\", \\"value\\"}\\". I have put a breakpoint just before the api call, and the data is all good, but on the server side it's weird.

Comment: This is how it's supposed to be: you have declared the service method as string and pass a JSON document generated by you it it -- so it gets encoded, because Gson/Retrofit do not have any idea that you're passing a JSON document. Why are you encoding twice? I mean, why do you need `getJsonString()`? Would making `uploadData` to accept `Object` along with `.upload(params)` work?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv yes that's the issue, i was actually encoding twice at these two lines `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` and `getJsonString(params)`. I passed hash map object to the `uploadData` and it's all good on the server side. Thanks mate.